# How can I append list accepted by user as value in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

**Code:-**

```
def store(s_name,loc):
    cat = []
    products = {}
    for i in range(1,h+1):
        a = input(f"Enter category {i}: ").title()
        cat.append(a)
    for x in cat:
        p = int(input(f"How many products are available in category {x}: "))
        for j in range(p):
            product_nm = input("Enter product name: ").title()
            products[x] = [product_nm]
            products[x].append(product_nm)
    p = f"*****************************************************************\nStore Name is {s_name}\nStore Location: {loc}\nCategories Available: {cat}\nVariety Includes: {products}"
    return p
s_name = input("Enter name of your store: ").upper()
loc = input("Enter city of your store: ").title()
h = int(input("How many categories are available: "))
z = store(s_name,loc)
print(z)
```

Instead of appending it's overwriting:

```
products[x] = [product_nm]
products[x].append(product_nm)
```

Please tell me what I can do?
I want output like this:

```
Variety Includes: {'Electronics': ['Smartphone', 'Computer'], 'Electricals': ['Air Conditioner', 'Refrigerator']}
```

**Output:-**

```
Variety Includes: {'Electronics': ['Smartphone', 'Smartphone'], 'Electricals': ['Air Conditioner', 'Air Conditioner']}
```

Comment: For your print you could do this : `f"{'*' * 40}\nStore Name is {s_name}\nStore Location: {loc}\nCategories Available: {cat}\nVariety Includes: {products}"` instead of using tons of '*'

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition around the part where you update the dictionary by adding an if statement that checks if the field already exists.

```
product_nm = input("Enter product name: ").title()
if x in products:
    products[x].append(product_nm)
else:
    products[x] = [product_nm]
```